Does next-auth somehow manage to save values in cookies in incognito too?
I tried to check my app authentication in incognito mode, but surprisingly, it was already logged in.
When I checked, in cookies the values were already present.
It's the same thing even after closing the incognito window and opening the other one.
I don't understand how I get the values already stored, as I have followed the proper documentation
There is a session call that's happening in the network tab, I guess that's what's setting it?
Need clarity on this. Has anybody else faced this?

When you say you closed the incognito window, was it the only one open? Browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Edge) I believe only support one incognito session, meaning incognito window 1 and incognito window 2 (if you open two if them) are both part of the same session and thus share/persist the same cookies/session data.

I guess that's what was happening, maybe another session was active and hence it was persistent.
